# Displaying an AlertDialog is crashing my app.

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've created an `AlertDialog` and put it on a `Button` `OnClickListener`.
However, the dialog is crashing my app.

what is wrong in my code?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            MyActivity.this.finish();
       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Comment: What do you see in logcat ? any exceptions ?

Comment: Does the application crash when you try to display the dialog or when you interact with it?  Your code looks okay, what there is of it, but it requires more context. I'd suggest posting more of the Activity code would help, at the very least the onCreate() and onCreateDialog() methods.  Also, as mentioned by Madushan, the contents of the logcat will also give strong clues as to the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

before

```
MyActivity.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code. it works

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   CharSequence[] items = { “Google”, “Apple”, “Microsoft” };
        boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean [items.length];
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.main);
             Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
               btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(0);
       }
         });
     }
      @Override
         protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
         switch (id) {
         case 0:
          return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
       .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
       .setTitle("This is a dialog with some simple text...")
         .setPositiveButton("OK", new
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
            int whichButton)
      {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                               "OK clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
         })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
     int whichButton)
     {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
       "Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
      })
      )
     .create();
     }
    return null;
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Json_ReadActivity.this);
builder.setMessage("are you sure want to exit");
builder.setNeutralButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

builder.show();
```